# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 error

Tags: 7

I get this `Notice`:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   custom_context_section_condition->_get_url_section() (line 110 of
>   modules/custom/custom_context/plugins/custom_context_section_condition.inc).

```
  **
  * Get section by url
  */
  function _get_url_section() {
    // get the correct URL
    $path = $_GET['q'];
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    }
    $path = explode('/', $path);

    // Remove reserved part from path when defined as constant (see custom_context.module)
    if (in_array(arg(0), unserialize(URL_PATH_PART))) {
      array_shift($path);
    }
    // Remove reserved string from path when defined as constant (see custom_context.module)
    else if ($new_path = _custom_context_strpos_replace_arr($_GET['q'], unserialize(URL_PATH_STRING))) {
      $path = explode('/', $new_path);
    }

    // Get section by path
    $value = str_replace('-', ' ', $path[1]);
    $terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($value);

    // make sure we are getting the right section under the correct city
    // check if city context exist
    $city = NULL;
    $contexts = context_active_contexts();
    if ($contexts = context_active_contexts()) {
      foreach ($contexts as $key => $context) {
        if ($key == 'city') {
          $city = $context->conditions['custom_city']['city']['term'];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      $city_context = new custom_context_city_condition(this, array());
      $cities = $city_context->_get_city($node);
      $city = array_shift($cities);
    }

    // check parent tid here
    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
      $parents = taxonomy_get_parents($term->tid);
      $parent = array_shift($parents);
      if ($city->tid != $parent->tid) {
        unset($terms[$key]);
      }
    }
    return $terms;
  }
```

This part:

```
if ($city->tid != $parent->tid) {
  unset($terms[$key]);
}
```

Also says: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Any idea whats wrong in my code?

Comment: The value of $path is `Array ( [0] => node )`, would that be a problem?

Comment: Please add line numbers or tell us where line 110 is in the first code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code above `$parent` is an array so `$parent->tid` is illegal. I am not sure what you are trying to find in the `$parent` but you should also note that the parent array has numeric indicies. So you probably have to do it this wat `$parent[45]` or `$parent[$city->tid]` depending on your requirement

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, either $city or $parent isn't an object. They are NULL of an other type. Have a look with your debugger or dump the contens of the variables to see what they contain.